# how to bind URL param (key, values) to html fields dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a URL, and html form like below, if any of the key matches to any of the field’s ID then bind value to that field.

I wrote below script, it is working fine when the field ids, param name are static.

How to bind the dynamic values to the associated dynamic fields by looping through the URL’s param (key, value) using JavaScript only.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]msg(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)");
var results = regex.exec(url);
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = !results ? "" : !results[2] ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

HTML form:

```
<input type="text" id="URL" value="http://xxxxz.com?email=bob@gmail.com&country=us&gender=male&msg=recordupdated" />    
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="text" id="email" />
<label>Country:</label>
<select id="country">
    <option value="ind">India</option>
    <option value="us">USA</option>
</select>
<label>Gender:</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female
<span id="msg"></span>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this method : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0d5g9j7/2/)

*This is with the assumption that the id or name  of the element will be same as the parameter name in url.*

```js
function setValues() {
  var s = document.getElementById("URL").value;
  var queryString = s.split("?");
  var params = queryString[1].split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var attribs = params[i].split("=");
    if (attribs[0] === "msg") continue;
    var elem = document.getElementById(attribs[0]);
    var newVal = '';
    if (elem) {
      newVal = elem.value
    } else {
      elem = document.getElementsByName(attribs[0]);
      for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (elem[i].checked) {
          newVal = elem[i].value;
        }
      }
    }
    params[i] = attribs[0] + "=" + (newVal == null ? '' : newVal);
  }
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = queryString[0] + "?" + params.join("&");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="URL" value="http://xxxxz.com?email=bob@gmail.com&country=us&gender=male&msg=recordupdated" style="width:100%;" />
<br/>
<label>Email:</label>
<input type="text" id="email" value="test@test.com" />
<label>Country:</label>
<select id="country">
  <option value="ind">India</option>
  <option value="us">USA</option>
</select>
<label>Gender:</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" checked/>Female
<hr/>
<span id="msg"></span>
<hr/>
<button type="submit" onclick="setValues()">Submit</button>
```

*P.S. : I know its bit lengthy and uses `.split` & `for` loops etc.. But i came up with this to keep the solution very simple. Suggestions to improve this are welcome :)*